# Swap elements between two tensors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert the following Numpy snippet:

```py
A = np.arange(10)
B = np.arange(10)**2

indices = np.random.randint(size=(5), low = 0, high = 9)
A[indices], B[indices] = B[indices], A[indices]
```

into Tensorflow operations. Essentially I'm trying to swap labels in a DCGAN since that's one of the things I've read help with training GANs.

This is my Tensorflow code right now:

```py
fake_labels = tf.random.uniform(shape=(batch_size,1), minval = 0.05, maxval = 0.15)
real_labels = tf.random.uniform(shape=(batch_size,1), minval = 0.7, maxval = 0.95)

indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=(batch_size//8,1), minval=0, maxval=batch_size-1, dtype=tf.int32)
fake_labels[indices], real_labels[indices] = real_labels[indices], fake_labels[indices] #swap
```

When I try doing this, I get the following error:

```py
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3 for \
'{{node strided_slice_1}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, \
end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](random_uniform_1, \
strided_slice_1/stack, strided_slice_1/stack_1, strided_slice_1/stack_2)' \
with input shapes: [?,1], [1,?,1], [1,?,1], [1].
```

Is this doable in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For random number generation part, it is recommended to use the new API `tf.random.Generator` to generate random number.

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers

See below for an example of random number generation and swapping elements between tensors.

Example codes:

```
@tf.function
def sampling_without_replacement(unnormalized_log_probs,K,rand_generator,dtype=tf.float32):
    z = -tf.math.log(-tf.math.log(rand_generator.uniform(tf.shape(unnormalized_log_probs),minval=0,maxval=1,dtype=dtype)))
    _, indices = tf.math.top_k(unnormalized_log_probs + z,k=K)
    return indices

#random number generation
rand_generator=tf.random.Generator.from_seed(88883)
batch_size=10
ratio=2
num_elem_to_swap=batch_size//ratio
a=rand_generator.uniform((batch_size,1),0.05,0.15)
b=rand_generator.uniform((batch_size,1),0.7,0.95)
indices_to_swap=sampling_without_replacement(tf.zeros((batch_size,),dtype=tf.float32),num_elem_to_swap,rand_generator)

for i,z in enumerate(zip(a.numpy(),b.numpy())):
  x,y=z
  print(f'{i}\t{x[0]:.5f}\t{y[0]:.5f}')
print(f'indices to swap: {indices_to_swap}')

#swapping
diff=b-a
indices_to_swap=tf.stack([indices_to_swap,tf.zeros((num_elem_to_swap,),dtype=tf.int32)],1)
diff*=tf.scatter_nd(indices_to_swap,tf.ones((num_elem_to_swap,)),(batch_size,1))
a+=diff
b-=diff

for i,z in enumerate(zip(a.numpy(),b.numpy())):
  x,y=z
  print(f'{i}\t{x[0]:.5f}\t{y[0]:.5f}')
'''
0   0.09812 0.72957
1   0.05188 0.91595
2   0.08754 0.72961
3   0.14588 0.77015
4   0.06716 0.89254
5   0.14450 0.85160
6   0.10091 0.90365
7   0.07445 0.75118
8   0.10370 0.93164
9   0.06084 0.83960
indices to swap: [9 6 4 8 5]
0   0.09812 0.72957
1   0.05188 0.91595
2   0.08754 0.72961
3   0.14588 0.77015
4   0.89254 0.06716
5   0.85160 0.14450
6   0.90365 0.10091
7   0.07445 0.75118
8   0.93164 0.10370
9   0.83960 0.06084
'''
```